# Optimizar subida de imagen

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, img

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.net CORE donde desde un  subimos imagenes a sql pasando por base64string y almaceno la string en una column en sql, mi pregunta es cuando uso el mobil para subir la imagen demora bastante tiempo, supongo yo que sera por la calidad de imagen, alguna forma de optimizar la demora y bajar la calidade de imagen para guardar la string en sql y en caso necesario reinvertirlo y bajar la imagen en su estado normal?

Comment: Como buenas practicas te **recomiendo** que nunca subas las imagenes a SQL sube las a archivos/recursos compartidos y guarda la URL de dicha carpeta en tu SQL

Comment: Son imagenes de documentos o foto simples de cara nada mas, y si estan en la sql es para estar cada individuo por id con su foto, no se como poderia hacerlo de la forma que dices tu, seria copiar cada url a un user path?

Comment: En mi opinión una foto por pequeña que sea siempre ocupa mas que un string, la foto simplemente la guardas en el tipico disco duro local o nube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas utilizando una aplicación web que se utiliza desde el móvil (no nativa) y todavía no quieres utilizar Blazor (dale una mirada después)
Para optimizar en el cliente las imagenes (o sea en el browser del móvil que esta subiendo la aplicación) vas a tener que "manipularlas en el cliente", para redimensionarla y bajar el tamaño, para luego enviarla.

Mira este proyecto de ejemplo

- [Pica demo](http://nodeca.github.io/pica/demo/) > High quality image resize in browser

Repo: https://github.com/nodeca/pica

**Con respecto a guardar en la DB** Depende de que base de datos, hay formas diferentes de guardar blobs. Por ejemplo en SQL Server (las ultimas versiones). Debes evaluar cual te conviene para el tipo de archivo de imagen en el universo del negocio del problema que tienes (no es lo mismo la imagen de un usuario para su avatar, que las imagenes de rayos x para un plataforma de salud)
Justamente en un post anterior escribi esto, espero que te sirva.

En el SQL server puedes utilizar para guardar imagenes:

VARBINAY(MAX) Pero puedes agregar "caracteristicas" a estas tablas que tiene VARBINARY, porque tiene un limite que 2GB. Por ejemplo FileStream. Microsoft propopne que tus archivos blob son de mas de 1MB entonces utiliza FileStream. Dale una mirada porque esto guarda en disco los archivos (pero lo administra el motor SQL) y es transparanete para la aplicación incluso y para los script que utilizamos para INSERT en la tabla. 
Ademas hay un tipo nuevo de tabla que se llama FileTable (nuevo en el SQL 2012) que es tener ya una carpeta con subcarpetas que puedas guardar y recuperar datos incluso por fuera del SQL.

Dale una mirada a estos enlaces y mira cual te conviene.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.